# is it a bad practice to require as parameter from a service in ModuleA, a service located in ModuleB?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My questions other than if is possible or not is about, will it be redundant? or will I end up have a strong dependency between them? or anyways would be the same if I dont.

The problem:

I have two modules in a single project (gradle/kotlin)

Module A has its own services and works fine.
Module B now requires to include module A to avoid duplicating code and then invoke a method from a service of module A.

So, on the constructor might look like this:

```
MyServiceModuleA( service myServiceModuleB) {
...
}
```

So I will be able to invoke them all...

Instead, if I want to stay "agnostic" about it I can receive as parameter all required fields to create my own MyServiceModuleB...

Lets say the constructor is like this

```
MyServiceModuleB(String name, String age, // other 4){
...
}
```

Then I would do:

```
 MyServiceModuleA( String name, String age, //other 4) {
    this.myServiceModuleB = new ServiceModuleB(name, age, ...);
  }
```

Is there any anti-pattern I should be aware or it and know which option to avoid?

Comment: Why not have a common module that both rely on?

Comment: API model itself be segregated as a separate distributable/dependency

Comment: _"Module A has its own services"_ -  In general, services are components that should be shared across *multiple* "modules".  So it doesn't really make sense to say that ModuleA has "its own" services.  Rather, there should be services that ModuleA can use if it needs to, but which can be used by other modules as well.  The services should have no knowledge of what modules they're being used by, nor should any of the modules know about each other.

Comment: @Michael what advantages would have to merge them both in a single module? ModuleA is available without call ModuleB but ModuleB is not

Comment: @jpganz18 Not what I said. Common stuff in new Module C. Module A and B rely upon Module C. Now Module B doesn't depend upon Module A.